# Chart.js and "pretty" date x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm testing `Chart.js` and it really seems nice and easy to use.
However, I have one challenge.

I've got a dataset of various hourly timestamps, ex.:

```
my_timestamps = ['2018-07-02 11:00', '2018-07-02 15:00', '2018-07-02 19:00', ...]
```

As you can see they jump from ex. hour 11 to hour 15 etc.

Can I force `Chart.js` to show an x-axis which jumps pretty from hour 11, hour 12, hour 13 etc. even though I've only got records for some of the timestamps?

Or should I somehow make my `my_timestamps` data "pretty"?

Comment: Loop through your data, and add timestamps that don't exist.

Comment: But that seems to make my line dissapear on those records, as there aren't any data for the y-axis.